# C# .Net 6.0 German special characters are not saved properly on File

Tags: c#

I am saving a `Byte[]` on a File. File is created successfully and all English characters are fine but all German special characters `(ä, Ä, ö, Ö, ü, Ü, ß)` are written wrong. The code is as below:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
{
    Byte[] betreffData = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Subject: " + message.decSubject;
    fs.Write(betreffData, 0, betreffData.Length);
}
```

Output on txt file is

> Betreff: BersenbrÃ¼ck ./. Test GmbH

But the actual output should be

> Betreff: Bersenbrßck ./. Test GmbH

How can I get the actual German characters too in output?

Comment: It looks like writing the file is fine. Whatever you're using to look at it is the problem. It's interpreting the file as ASCII or ANSI, not UTF-8.

Comment: If this is a text file, why not work with this as string and not `Byte[]`? You can try `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)` where data is the byte array to make it a string and then persist it to file that way

Comment: Ã¼ is an ü not a ß. The tool you use to look at the string just doesn't know you are using utf-8 and shows you presumably a win-1252 representation.

Comment: What text editor do you use to check the output in your file?